# python for loop function output bring the same result over and over

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I wrote a function that check the validity of id
there is an algorithm that perform few calculation-first make sure that the len of the id is 9 then other calculation, the result should be divided by 10 and then the output will be True or False
list6 includes list of if list6=[21544622,301038725]
calling the function manually will bring the right result True or False, however in the loop something go wrong and get the same result

```
l=[]
ls=[]
count=0
num=[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
d=[]
list3=[]
def check_id(s):
    b=0
    z=0
    s=str(s)
    if len(s)<6:
        print("wrong id")
    elif len(s)==6:
        s='000'+s
    elif len(s)==7:
        s='00'+s
    elif len(s)==8:
        s='0'+s
    else:
        pass
    for digit in s:
        l.append(int(digit))
    b=list(zip(l,num))

    for k,v in b:
        d.append(k*v)
    for n in d:
        n=str(n)
        if len(n)==2:
            n=int(n[0])+int(n[1])

        else:
            n=int(n)
        list3.append(n)
    z=sum(list3)



    return z%10==0


for x in list6:

    check=0
    check=check_id(s=x)
    print(check)
```

Comment: This code can't possibly run, since `list6` is not defined.  Please post your real code.

Comment: You post value for list6 in your question i.e. `list6=[21544622,301038725] `.  It should also be in the code.

Comment: For ` list6=[21544622,301038725]`, should the result be True, True?

Comment: I am looping 6000 items thus did not share all the items , the result for this two items is True

Comment: the code is                                                                                                           import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
import pprint
from matplotlib import pyplot
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
p=pd.read_excel('Payroll13.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')                                       list6=[]
for i in p['id']:
    list6.append(i)

Comment: this is another example    for list6                                  21544622, 56599996, 204476485, 14021828, 25719352, 23031933, 29517299, 25719353, 31407836, 39931944, 40543449, 51283893, 301038725, 302776208, 40444994, 57046773, 58343302, 59813360, 66168980, 54871884, 22372981, 57000515                                   only one of them is false

Comment: this is an example   21544622-first make sure nine digit by add zero  (021544622) than multiply by(1,2,1,2,1,2,12,1) this brings (0 4 1 10 4 8 6 4 2 ) now need to sum the digit if there are two or leave one digit for one digit number this brings (4 1 1 4 8 6 4 2 ) this sum to 30 if divide to 10 with zero this true if no than false ,it works well manually for id  however in a loop something go wrong

Answer (score 0):

after few testing while I printed each step , I found my problem
I need to split each ID to different digits and then multiply it by 1 or 2
I missed this step and now this should work